# Bayes Rule - Expanding the conditional probabilties

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

Suppose I am generating a sample for $P(A=0|B=0,C=0,AvB=0,CvA=2,BvC=0)$
The pseudo probability for this would be given as:

$P'(A=0|B=0,C=0,AvB=0,CvA=2,BvC=0) = P(A=0)P(B=0,C=0,AvB=0,CvA=2,BvC=0|A=0)$

$P'(A=0|B=0,C=0,AvB=0,CvA=2,BvC=0) = P(A=0)P(B=0|A=0)P(C=0|A=0)P(AvB=0|A=0)P(CvA=2|A=0)P(BvC=0|A=0)$

$P'(A=0|B=0,C=0,AvB=0,CvA=2,BvC=0) = P(A=0)P(B=0)P(C=0)P(AvB=0|A=0)P(CvA=2|A=0)P(BvC=0)$

We would then compute the pseudo probabilities for the values of A=1,A=2,A=3. add them with the value for A=0 and it becomes our normalizer.
Then we divide the value of pseudo probability of A=0 with normalizer and we get the required answer.

A, B and C are independent of each other. AvB is dependent on A and B and so on.

I am getting the wrong answer for some reason. 
Could someone point out my mistake?
In my opinion the problem lies in the part where I expand the conditional probability in the second step.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What does $AvB$ mean?

Comment: It is another variable. with dependancies on A and B